# VirtualBox, no me sale la opcion de RED en preferencias

Tags: virtualbox, red

he emprezado a usar VirtualBox, estaba creando un servidor de apache, pero al probarlo me he encontrado el problema de que el cliente no lo encontraba, he visto que tenia que hacer una red NAT, pero en las preferencias no me da la opcion de RED

Answer (score 0):

Ahora esa opción se encuentra en

```
Archivo -> Herramientas -> Administrador de Red
```